# Returning data from URLSession in Swift

Tags: swift, api

I have tried to research this issue and am unable to find a suitable fix. I attached an image of the code. I am trying to return the subscriptions array which is declared before the URLSession, and data is appended during the URLSession. However, it returns the originally declared, empty array. I added print statements so you can understand what I am talking about. It prints 2 before 1.

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://utelly-tv-shows-and-movies-availability-v1.p.rapidapi.com/lookup?term=\(searchShow)&country=us")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            //let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            //print(json)

        } else {
            //let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let json = try! decoder.decode(results.self, from: data!)
            //print(json) (for debugging use only)
            //print(httpResponse)
            for item in json.results{
                for each in item.locations{
                    subscriptions.append(each.display_name)
                }
            }
            //Remove duplicates from array
            let uniqueUnordered = Array(Set(subscriptions))
            let uniqueOrdered = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: uniqueUnordered))
            subscriptions = uniqueOrdered as! [String]
            //Print subscriptions array
            print("1: \(subscriptions)")
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
    print("2: \(subscriptions)")
    return subscriptions
```

[image: output statements]

Comment: As you've figured out, the work assigned to the data task only executes when the task completes...and that is after your function returns.  A good fix is to have the caller pass a code block (closure) that does whatever is needed using `subscriptions` into your function.  You then call that block about where you're currently printing "1: ..." instead of trying to return anything.

Comment: URLSession dataTask is asynchronous. What happens there is that you are trying to return the result right after starting the task, before it actually completes the task. What you need is to add a completion handler to your method instead of trying to return a result synchronously.

Comment: Btw not related to your question but you should use `URLRequest` in Swift. If you need to mutate it just declare is as `var`.